# Copying a file and adding the date to its name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, getdate

Why doesn't this work?:

```
Copy-Item "C:\Logs\VPNLog.txt" "C:\Backup\VPNLog$(Get-Date -UFormat %d-%m-%Y-%R).txt"
```

Error message:
`Copy-Item : The given path's format is not supported.`

For the record, this works:

```
Copy-Item "C:\Logs\VPNLog.txt" "C:\Backup\VPNLog.txt"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `%R` is outputting the time formatted with colons, and filenames cannot have colons in them.  To see this, simply run `get-date -uformat %d-%m-%Y-%R`

To get the hours, minutes, and seconds there without colons, you'll need to use a get-date command similar to the following:

```
get-date -uformat %d-%m-%Y-%H.%M.%S
```

Comment: You probably mean M for minutes: get-date -uformat %d-%m-%Y-%H.%M.%S

Answer (score 0):

Its because your format contains a colon (`:`) which is not allowed for file names.

You can get a list of all invalid file characters using: `[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%R`, which per the notes, provides a `:` character in the filename, which is not supported.  Take out the `%R` or separate out the formatting of the date string first before appending the filename with that additional timestamp data.

Source: [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) for `Get-Date`